# Regex in spark.read.json

Tags: regex, apache-spark, hadoop

I want to read all json files which are having timestamp one hour before the current time from the hadoop directory.
File name is like test_2020021418553333

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

val form = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhh");

val c = Calendar.getInstance();

c.add(Calendar.HOUR, -1);

val path ="/Test_"+form.format(c.getTime())+"*";

val test_df = spark.read.json(path)
```

When I run this code: Path does not exist error is coming.
Can anyone suggest how to read file names like Test_20200214{Any Possible combination of Digit}??

Comment: Test_2020021418\d+

Comment: Not working @Eraklon

Comment: Do you have these files in hdfs or are they local?

Comment: You need to read the parent directory then filter out file names

Comment: And use DateTimeFormatter, please

Answer (score 1):

A quick test show that you have minutes

`form.format(c.getTime())
res2: String = 2020021401`

So remove the latest 2 cars

regards

Comment: Made the correction @Jeannot77680 but still not working

Comment: I miss time to verify if it spark.read.json which doesn't accept format. You can try the other way with  spark.read.format("json").load(path)